# how to get RemovedItems or AddedItems from combobox?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

what could be done if i want to get the removed itema dn added items from a comboBox?

Comment: Kumar: Need some more detail. When and how do you remove items and when do you want them.

Comment: when a selectionchange is happening in the combobox, i have to do some calculation to the removeditem object and i have to initialize some values to the added Item.

Comment: Kumar: By `AddedItem` do you mean the item currently selected and By `RemovedItem` the item previously selected? Also share some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any case bind your ComboBox's SelectedItem to a property in your ViewModel. The changes could be done to that property in the setter.

```
Foo _selectedItem;
public Foo SelectedItem
{
    get
    { 
        return _selectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        oldvalue = _selectedItem; // Do something with the previously SelectedItem
        _selectedItem = value; // Do something with the newly SelectedItem
        // PropertyChange Notification goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for binding the items of the combobox? if you are using a `ObservableCollection` you can use the `CollectionChanged` event to be notified of those changes. And it would all be done in the ModelView layer were you probably want to.